# Recursive query on jsonb data stored in Postgres

Tags: json, postgresql, recursion, nested

I have a table in postgres named 'books' with one jsonb column called 'j' with the following data:

```
{
  "entity": "Book",
  "processes": [
    {  "process": [
        { "processname": "Buy",
          "option": "none",
            "processes": [
              { "process": [
                { "processname": "Order",
                  "option": "none"
                }
                ]
              },
               { "process": [
                { "processname": "Arrive",
                  "option": "none"
                }
                ]
              },
               { "process": [
                { "processname": "Enter",
                  "option": "none"
                }
                ]
              }

             ]
        }
     ]
    },
    { "process": [
        { "processname": "Use",
          "option": "none",
    "processes": [
      { "process": [
          { "processname": "Lend",
            "option": "*",
"processes": [
    {
      "process": [
        {
          "processname": "Borrow",
          "option": "none"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "process": [
        {
          "processname": "Return",
          "option": "none"
        }
      ]
    }
 ]
          }
       ]
       } 
      ]
         }
]
    },
    {  "process": [
        { "processname": "Scrap",
          "option": "none",
           "processes": [
              { "process": [
                { "processname": "Sold",
                  "option": "0"
                }
                ]
              },
               { "process": [
                { "processname": "Scrap",
                  "option": "0"
                }
                ]
              }
        ]
    }
  ]
}
]
}
```

I want to retrieve all the **processnames** together with the **processnames of their parents (i.e. path taken to reach them)**.

I have the following code so far but the union part is not working.

```
with recursive jsonrecursion as
(
      select process -> 'processname' as processname, '{}'::int[] as superior, 0 as lv
        from books, jsonb_array_elements(j-> 'processes') processes, jsonb_array_elements(processes-> 'process') process
       where process -> 'processes' is NULL

         union all

      select process -> 'processname' as processname, superior ||  process -> 'processname', lv+1
        from    books, jsonrecursion
       where not process -> 'processname' = any(superior)
)

SELECT processname, superior, lv
FROM jsonrecursion;
```

Can someone kindly help please?
Thanks

Comment: Which Postgres version are you using?

Comment: Postgres Version 10.4

Comment: What exactly is the output you want?

Comment: I want to list all the 'process names' together with their parent if any. So for example Buy -> null, Order -> Buy, Arrive ->Buy, Enter -> Buy, Use -> null, Lend -> Use, Borrow - > Use >> Lend, Return -> Use >>Lend etc